# Replace a SQL Server query with another before execution

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to work with a legacy application in SQL Server which at some point does the following query

```
SELECT serverproperty('EngineEdition') as sqledition
```

The server replies with 2 (which is the correct edition), but the application closes since the app demands to be run over SQL Server Express which is 4. We don't have access to the code and the developer is long gone.

Is there a way to configure SQL Server so that when this query is received it simply returns 4 and not the value of the property?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off just installing Express and pointing it at that.  Anything you do regarding this is obviously a hack at best with unknown risks and consequences.  If the app has outgrown the limitations of Express then it's a good indicator that you need to move on from that app, even beyond the signs you've already mentioned that it's time to move on.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for squillman.
There is no way to override the return of "serverproperty".  If the code is written in .NET then you could get a developer to hack it (using Reflector or similar).  Since the query is likely in the source plain text you may even have some luck replacing it with a HEX editor to something like

```
SELECT 4 as sqledition
```

Comment: +1 Replacing the string would be a good hack

Comment: Note this would not work with files that have been digitally signed.  Not sure if that would be applicable here though.....